# MapView and Traffic

Tags: android, google-maps, traffic

I’m trying to add the traffic feature on my map with the setTraffic method, but without any changes. At the beginning I thought that for the area that I'm showing (Sydney) there wasn’t this feature, but after that I checked on Google Earth I saw that the traffic is correctly showed.

Any advice or any alternative solution?

```
MapView myMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
mapController = myMapView.getController();

myMapView.setSatellite(true);
myMapView.setStreetView(false);
myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);
myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myMapView.setTraffic(true);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?  You may have to turn the current overlay off before calling setTraffic(true)

Comment: I added the code. Whih overlay, the street view?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue - my MapView shows traffic OK in the USA but doesn't show it here in the UK. (I'm using an HTC Desire with Android 2.2). I have seen other apps achieve this (such as Glob - http://g-lob.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm having the same(similar) issue over at this question >>> [Why doesn't Google's MapView show traffic outside of the USA on Android 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444779/why-doesnt-googles-mapview-show-traffic-outside-of-the-usa-on-android-2-2)

Having run some tests it appears the MapView component in Android 2.2 **does not** show traffic outside of the United States whereas it **does** show it in Android 2.3.3.

Well, specifically I can state that using code identical to your's the above statement is true. It remains to be seen if there is an alternative way to get the non-USA traffic displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked properly.  Try calling invalidate on your MapView after changing the overlays:

```
myMapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: That would explain why it's working on my phone.  What version is it not working on?

Comment: It's not working on android 1.6 and 2.2. Do you know any alternatives for the google traffic? I saw that there are the yahoo web services, but they are going to close on september.